# how to print the midpoint rule in python

Tags: python

I have the following code to calculate the midpoint of a function and then output the approximate area under the graph but I can't get it to print it is saying there is one missing required attribute of 'points', I'm not sure if this is something to do with the code itself or just trying to print the result. any ideas on how to fix this?

```py
def midpoint(f, xmin, xmax, points):
    h = float(xmax-xmin)/points
    result = 0
    for i in range(points):
        result += f((xmin + h/ 2.0) + i*h)
    result *= h
    return result
print (midpoint(points,xmin,xmax))
```

Comment: Please paste your code in a code block within your question.

Comment: Yes and do fix it so args in the print statement match the function definition

Comment: **Never** post code or error messages in images or link to external sites. **Always** provide them into the question as text formatted in code blocks.

Comment: @EliHarold those formatting issues don’t affect how the code runs

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the function input.

```
midpoint(f, xmin, xmax, points)
```

So you have to give `f`
You have:

```
midpoint(points, xmin, xmax)
```